# useInfiniteQuery refetching all pages on single record mutation

Tags: react-native, react-query

I am using `useInfiniteQuery` with FlatList in React Native. In one of item in the list there is toggle functionality. I have successfully used `useMutation` and it works great.

When user scrolls and reach to end I fetch another page. Let's say I have loaded 5 pages i.e. 5 requests on the server. Now I go to the top on the first page and toggle first record using mutation. I used

```
onSettled: () => queryClient.invalidateQueries(key)
```

I observed that this causes all pages fetch in background i.e. again 5 requests on the server to fetch all pages which are already there and only for just one record.

so my question is that is it possible to avoid all page request and refetch only the page which was changed. I tried to look in documentation but couldn't find anything helpful on this.

Comment: Did you found a solution to this?

Comment: nope, yet not found any viable solution